# Dynamically add HTML items to the right of previous item instead of below

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm sure this is an amateur question, but I am having difficulty figuring out how to dynamically add html items to the right(same horizontal level) inside of my div.  When I add a new Label it adds below the previous label I added.  How do I place the new Label to the right of the previous label I added to my webpage?

My javascript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#comp").click(function (e){
 event.preventDefault()

$('#items').append('<label>My Label</label>+
        '<input>'+
        '<br>'+
        '<label>Second Label</label>');

});

});

</script>
```

My html:

```
<div id = "items">

</div>

<input type="button", name = "comp" value = "Compare" id="comp"></input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to alter your HTML to be standard to demonstrate, but the answer is use `display:inline-block` as a style on the added label

```js
$("#comp").click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const item = '<label>My Label</label> <input> <br> <label>Second Label</label>';
  $('#items').append('<div class="newitem">' + item + ' </div>');

});
```

```css
#items .newitem {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#items .newitem input {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items">

</div>

<input type="button" name="comp" value="Compare" id="comp" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I think I am close. It works as you have it, but I edited my post since I have a few more items that I will need to add. Once I add a <br> for a new line, it seems to break the code and no longer adds to the right. Any ideas?

Comment: @MC2020 - not sure if this is what you had in mind, but I updated my answer

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the styling to inline. Either change from a `div` to a `span` or, add change the div to `<div style="display: inline"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Add a display of flex to `#items`, then you can add margin on label or gap on `#items`. With flex you can also control justify-content prop as well...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comp").click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#items').append('<label>My Label</label>');
  });
});
```

```css
#items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  /* gap: 1rem; <-- alternative */
}

label {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="items">

</div>

<input type="button" , name="comp" value="Compare" id="comp">
```